# How to delete default Measure Groups in the SSAS CUBE?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

I have created a CUBE. By default CUBE created few Measure Groups.

When I go to Aggregations, I can see the default Measure Groups. I want to delete them all and want to create as per the requirement.

Attached is the screenshot,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to delete a Measure Group from your cube, you can simply go to `Cube Structure` tab and right click on the Measure Group and select `Delete`.

[image]